# Outlook 2019 shows error 0xCAA80000 after migration to Microsoft 365

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

Our IT has migrated our email inboxes to Microsoft 365 and since migration, my Outlook cannot connect to server. My email account was already configured from before and it just disconnected from server. When it tries to connect again, I get a message "**We can't connect you. Looks like we can't connect to one of our services right now. Please try again later, or contact your helpdesk if the issue persists.
0xCAA80000
login.microsoftonline.com**"
[See Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrbx6.png)

My admin removed my email account from outlook but still we face the same error when we try to add it again.
I have tried to check this issue, I tried to run SFC and done many things with no luck.
I have found something may be useful. In the Windows Event Viewer, I get these errors when I try to add my account now. [See Event Viewer error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQr5O.png)

I noticed that the URL in the error is
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c&redirect_uri=ms-appx-web^3a^2f^2fMicrosoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin^2fd3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c&instance_aware=true&nonce=e11b17c4-368c-4919-9204-f62aebb59c75&resource=https^3a^2f^2fautodiscover-s.outlook.com^2f&add_account=multiple&prompt=login&login_hint=aelmaghazy^40ejada.com&response_mode=form_post&claims=^7b^22access_token^22^3a^7b^22xms_cc^22^3a^7b^22values^22^3a^5b^22CP1^22^5d^7d^7d^7d&msafed=0&windows_api_version=2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c&redirect_uri=ms-appx-web%5E3a%5E2f%5E2fMicrosoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin%5E2fd3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c&instance_aware=true&nonce=e11b17c4-368c-4919-9204-f62aebb59c75&resource=https%5E3a%5E2f%5E2fautodiscover-s.outlook.com%5E2f&add_account=multiple&prompt=login&login_hint=aelmaghazy%5E40ejada.com&response_mode=form_post&claims=%5E7b%5E22access_token%5E22%5E3a%5E7b%5E22xms_cc%5E22%5E3a%5E7b%5E22values%5E22%5E3a%5E5b%5E22CP1%5E22%5E5d%5E7d%5E7d%5E7d&msafed=0&windows_api_version=2.0)
which is not correctly encoded as I think the ^ character should be % character.
I tried to open the link as it is, get this error

"**Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute URI.**"

But when I replace ^ character by % character the link opens normally and asks me for my password.

How to fix this?

Comment: Related to the date in the Event Viewer, Date is correctly adjusted, but it is shown in Hijri Calendar, not Gregorian.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue can only be solved by the author’s IT administrator.

Comment: IT Administrator is requesting help too! Email Account works with other PCs but the problem is in my laptop. He told me to reinstall Windows to solve the issue

Comment: Let me rephrase.  This issue is something only your Administrator can solve, it’s very unlikely, reinstalling Windows will resolve this problem.  The error suggests a Office 365 account configuration problem not a Outlook/Windows configuration problem

Comment: @Ramhound Same account can be configured on another machine. We tried this and it worked. So I believe the problem is in my laptop.

Comment: No;  It's not the device.  Has your system administrator tried deleting your Outlook profile?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, he tried. Anyway, issue is solved by disabling ADAL at my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue by a work around. I found a way to disable using ADAL plugin for Outlook.
Steps:

1. Open Registery Editor
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity
3. At the right pane, double-click at EnableADAL REG_DWORD value, and set the value data to 0.
   Note: If the value, doesn't exist, then create it. (From 'Edit' menu, go to New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value, and then type "EnableADAL" without quotes)
4. Then create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value with name DisableADALatopWAMOverride
5. Open the newly created value and set the value data to 1
6. Close the registry editor and restart your PC.

Taken from: https://www.wintips.org/fix-outlook-authentication-with-office-365-fails/

This worked for me.

Comment: Glad to see that your issue has been figured out. Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: By the way, would you mind marking your own reply as answer so that others who might have a similar question can benefit from your thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. Exit Outlook and open the Registry Editor
2. Navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0
3. Right-click the Outlook folder
4. Rename it as Outlook1
5. Restart your Outlook and add your email account to test

If the issue still continues, please try to check your connection between your Outlook and your mail server via [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Ola/input).